# Is this an absolute construction?

Tags: participle-phrases, absolute-construction

Is this an example of a nominative absolute phrase?

> There was a stall that sold masks in the local market on Sunday mornings. He looked at many different masks. **Most of them, too outlandish, he rejected out of hand.**

[A wrinkle in the realm by Ben Okri]

Comment: No: An absolute is a non-finite clause containing a subject and functioning as a supplementary adjunct, as in "[His hands gripping the door], he let out a volley of curses". Your example is one of the preposing of the object of "rejected".

Comment: And one more thing about these so-called _absolutes_: While it's okay to say _Dagger in hand, he rushed forward to assault the man_, is it also okay to say _John absent, we decided to cancel the meeting_? All I'm doing is omitting _being_ from both examples, but the _John_ example doesn't sound correct to me. Why is that?

Comment: "John absent, ..." is the verbless analogue of "John being absent ...".

Comment: @BillJ can a verbless clause be an Absolute construction? And in sentence like this "with the machine still running, it is about time to get this done.", is "with the machine still running" an absolute construction? Or "the machine still running" an absolute construction?

Comment: @Man_From_India  Yes, I believe that "John absent" qualifies as an absolute.  Absolutes are always non-finite clauses, and since "with the machine still running" is a preposition phrase, not a clause, I believe that it does not qualify as an absolute.

Comment: @BillJ But a verbless clause is not a non finite verb.

Comment: @Man_From_India The only kind of clause that would fit is a non-finite one, i.e. "John being absent, we decided to cancel the meeting". A finite clause would not be possible: *"John is absent, we decided to cancel the meeting". "John absent, we decided to cancel the meeting", is thus the verbless analogue of your example. and I'd say that qualifies as an absolute. Note, though, that it would be rare for anyone to use the verbless clause.

Comment: @BillJ but in describing absolute construction, as far as I remember, H & P says it is the non finite clause with certain conditions. I don't have the book right now to confirm. But it is what I think it is.

Comment: @Man_From_India The conditions are that they consist of a non-finite clause with a subject, and that they function as a supplement. They thus have no syntactic link to the main clause, hence the term 'absolute'.

Comment: @BillJ yes but I don't think they consider verbless clause as non-finite clause. Yes verbless clause might be comparable to a non finite clause in the example "john absent".bif one is not a non finite clause, then there is no question of absolute construction.

Comment: @Man_From_India Compare these examples, both supplements: _His hands gripping the edge of the cliff, he screamed out for help_ and the verbless _His face pale with anger, he stormed out of the room_. I'd say that the latter is just as much an absolute as the former.

Comment: @BillJ H & P doesn't explicitly says so, neither does OMEG which says verbless clauses are similar to non finite clause.

Comment: @Man_From_India Believe whatever you want!

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't an example of a nominative absolute phrase. It is an example of a *parenthetical clause*. You could remove the part of the sentence between the commas and it would still make sense:

- Most of them he rejected out of hand.

The fact that they are 'too outlandish' is presented as additional information which is not necessary to the sentence.

A nominative absolute phrase is a non-finite clause (not phrase) that contains a subject and functions as a supplementary adjunct, for example:

- Most of them being too outlandish, he rejected many out of hand.

Comment: It would be preferable to define an absolute as a non-finite clause (not phrase) that contains a subject and functions as a supplementary adjunct.

Comment: @BillJ That's certainly a more technical description, I've updated it as you suggest, I hope the OP understands it.